# Is there anything built into to Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 to align table contents?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

It is easy to align table by setting "align" attribute, but table aligning by css is a bit hacky. Is there built-in support for tables aligning in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure this is 'hacky'. Bootstrap is just that a bootstrap to get things started and is meant to be built upon.

Answer (score 24):

There is nothing built in to support this but it is very easy to add something like:

```
.table th.rightCell,
.table td.rightCell {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively to keep Bootstrap's naming conventions and to utilize the pre-built `text-right` class, you should add this to your own css:
`.table th.text-right, .table td.text-right {
   text-align: right;
}`

and then use

`<td class="text-right">Ta-dam</td>`

Answer (score 12):

Bootstrap's [alignment classes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography) include `.text-right` which sets `text-align: right`.

Unfortunately Bootstrap sets `text-align: left` for table cells so applying `.text-right` to a `<td>` doesn't have any effect:

```
<td class="text-right">
  Still left aligned
</td>
```

Adding `.text-right` to a block element *inside* the cell however does work:

```
<td>
  <p class="text-right">Right aligned</p>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="text-right">Right aligned</div>
</td>
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.0, and `.text-right` works perfectly when applied directly to a `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

For "td" I used this which is included in bootstrap css:

```
<td class="pagination-centered">
```

Comment: "pagination-centered" <- it's too long (19 chars). I'd rather use a shorter classnames.